# Display message if database not found in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Sorry if this is a simple question, i am trying to find solution But i can't find it.

Can you please give me a suggestion to resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer

I checked whether the database is exist or not using the below code.

```
$this->load->dbutil();
$dbs_smarttips = $this->dbutil->list_databases();
if (!$this->dbutil->database_exists('DB NAME'))
{
  show_error("Database not exists", 500 );
  exit;
}
```

It return an error with `Database not exists`, You can also redirect it.

[Reference link](http://smarttips.in/check-database-exists-in-codeigniter/)

Comment: Where should this be placed? Greetings

Answer (score 1):

In applications folder there is a folder named **errors**. There are all error files which comes up when an error is occurred.

When database error is occurred, **error_db.php** file is shown in browser. You can edit it or replace that with your custom file.

Comment: Thanks, you should review my answer

Answer (score 1):

Inside

```
`application/views/errors/cli/error_db.php'
```

with following code

```
  <?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

echo "\nDatabase error: ",
    $heading,
    "\n\n",
    $message,
    "\n\n";
```

you can make your 'custom message' here.

Comment: Thanks, you should review my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
} else {
    echo "Database found";
}
?>
```

Refer [this](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_connect.asp)